# innerHTML doesn't add HTML elements permanently

Tags: html, innerhtml, appendchild

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `innerHTML` in the code below. I want to permanently add a new `div` block every time I hit the button, but it seems that the new block only pops up for a split second then disappears.

Does anyone know why this is the case, and how to fix it?

Also, when I change the code to use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`, I get an error saying `Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.`. I'm not sure what this means.

Any help is much appreciated!

Below is the code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form onSubmit="loadData()">
            <input type="submit" id="button">
        </form>

        <div id="block">List of items:</div>

        <script>
            function loadData(){
                document.getElementById("block").innerHTML += "<div>item</div>";
            //  document.getElementById("block").appendChild("<div>item</div>");

            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using a submit button which causes a reload. Use a regular button and you won't have this problem.

Comment: So I replace the input tag with this `<button id="button">Submit</button>`.
Nothing seem to happen when I hit the button

Comment: that's because your code is only adding items "onSubmit". See my solution and comments...

Comment: Ah ok, so that part is solved.
Do you happen to know why appendChild doesn't work in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are submitting then the page reloads and your HTML is obliterated.

If you need items to persist then you will need to use cookies, localStorage or a server-side solution.

```js
function addItem() 
{
  document.getElementById("block").innerHTML += "<div>item</div>";
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="button" id="button" onclick="addItem()" />
    </form>

    <div id="block">List of items:</div>


  </body>

  </html>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

you are submitting the page. appendChild or innerHtml happen directly after submit, before the new page is loaded. once the new page is loaded, the current page (with the applied modifications) is dismissed and replaced with the new page.

if you wanted something to happen on the new page, you would need to execute the code on that page. (or don't use a form submit, but rather some ajax for sending the form).

The reason why appendChild is not working for you, is that appendChild expects a dom node as parameter, not a string. it would be like `document.getElementById("foo).appendChild(document.createElement("div"))`. (the tricky part is that with createElement you get an empty element, you would also need to put the content you want into it.

Comment: Thanks Matthias! I want to try using ajax to send the form, as this is something new to me. Do you mind giving me an example code showing how to adopt ajax in my case above?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is already answered by @lee.
Your problem with your second answer is, that you can not use appendChild like you did. If u want to use append child, according to the [mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) you will have to to something like this:

```
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("item"));
document.getElementById("block").appendChild(mydiv);
```

to get the result you asked for.

Comment: Thanks suits_at!
Assuming that, instead of just adding the text "item", I want to add some attributes to the newly created div, e.g. class, height, width attributes, how can I do this?

Comment: You can create attribute nodes in the same way. For an easier handling of the code I juste made a short codepen for you.
https://codepen.io/suits_at/pen/WwppMy